# AngularJs: Dealing with two SPAs and routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I have two SPAs: one has `<base href="/">` and other has `<base href="/dashboard/">`

And I am deploying these applications as separate `war` files in tomcat server. So far this is working good.

Let's have a look in my code (second app config i.e for /dashboard/):

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.when('/events', {
        templateUrl: 'event-list/event-list.html',
        controller: 'eventListCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: ' ',
        controller: ['$scope','$location', function($scope,$location) {
            $location.path('events');
            $location.replace(); // problem #1
        }]
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'}); // problem #2
}]);
```

**Problem #1**

As you can see in code, I want to redirect the URL `http://localhost/dashboard` to `http://localhost/dashboard/events` by default. But this configuration is giving me **maximum call stack exceeded** error in browser console.

**Problem #2**

I already have 404 page in my first app i.e. at `http://localhost/404` location. But my current configuration is redirecting me to `http://localhost/dashboard/404`. I want to reuse my 404 page.

Please guide me in right direction. Thanks.

Comment: the second problem could be because, you are running only one SPA at a time. and thats the dashboard one. localhost can host only one app at a port at a time. That might be the dashboard one. Try killing dashboard one, and run the other one, and then try this 404 page.

Comment: @Shivi, I can't kill non-dashboard app because both run together. Consider this, they are deployed in production and I want to use `http://localhost/404` url.